# How to increase or decrease web browser control font size using button?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Hi i am using web browser control.I have two button increase and decrease.I want to increase or decrease web view content

My xaml code

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Webbrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
```

My xaml.cs code

```
private void zoom_out(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (j > 0)
        {
            Webbrowser.FontSize -= 2;

            j--;
            i = j;
        }
    }
    private void zoom_in(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (i < 3)
        {
            Webbrowser.FontSize += 2;

            i++;
            j = i;
        }
    }
```

I tried this code but i cant increase or decrease web view font size.i am struggling long time.please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario FontSize of the WebBrower control wont work as you need to set the FotnSize for the content which is rendered from the html page. Hence you may try `ScaleTransform` in `WebBrowser.RenderTransform` option to achieve this. I think it may help you.

Comment: Hi thanks to replay, I cant set WebBrowser.RenderTransform i think it may be works on windows form but am using windows phone

Comment: you have to use like this. <phone:WebBrowser.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" x:Name="scaletrans"/>
                </phone:WebBrowser.RenderTransform>